# xpdo modx how to add a condition ON DUPLICATE

Tags: php, mysql, modx, xpdo

I have a very simple MySQL table and I need to execute this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO modx_good (uuid,name) VALUES ('1','name')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uuid='1', name='name';
```

My table is `modx_good`:

```sql
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`uuid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

And I need to run this using features of [modx and xpdo](https://docs.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/class-reference/xpdoquery/xpdoquery.orcondition).

I can insert data by

```php
$modGood = $this->modx->newObject('Good');
$modGood->fromArray([ 
  'uuid' => 'a1', 
  'name' => 'name1'
]);
$modGood->save();
```

But how can I add the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` condition that I had in the raw query?

Comment: But the key cannot be duplicated here, since you don't give a key yourself...

Comment: uuid is uniq, i tested query, works fine, if there is a same uuid it updates all other fields not creating new input. I found this query in google and it seems to work just fine, my problem is i have to make the same using modx xpdo. on duplicate - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: To my knowledge xPDO doesn't support `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, so you wont have much luck doing this through the object related methods. You could craft the query yourself and fire it off as prepared statement with $modx->query() though. See https://docs.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/class-reference/xpdo/xpdo.query